# pasar valor a otro Método

Tags: java

estoy realizando un programa de practica (Cajero automático) cuya función es depositar, retirar y verificar el balance actual. he creado 3 métodos cada uno hará su función mi pregunta es la siguiente; he realizado el método de depositar :

**@Overrider**

```
public void depositar() {

    Caja caja = new Caja();
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL MONTO QUE DESEA DEPOSITAR:");
    caja.setDeposito(entrada.nextInt());
    int resultado = caja.getConsulta()+ caja.getDeposito();
    System.out.println("Balance actual = " + resultado);
```

}

Ahora al momento de realizar el método de **(consultar el balance)** no se me muestra el balance actual, sino se me muestra el balance del por default, como hago para colocarle el deposito a mi método balance?

```
 @Override

    public void consulta() {

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

En lugar de crear una instancia de la clase `Caja` dentro de los métodos se crea dentro de la clase que contiene esos métodos, de esa forma todos los métodos la comparten.

```
public class Cajero {
        // instancia que será compartida por los métodos
        private Caja caja = new Caja();
    
        public void depositar() {
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("INTRODUZCA EL MONTO QUE DESEA DEPOSITAR:");
            caja.setDeposito(entrada.nextInt());
            int resultado = caja.getConsulta() + caja.getDeposito();
            System.out.println("Balance actual = " + resultado);
        }
    
        public void consultar() {
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias! Logre resolver el problema.